# How to get index in for case pattern matching loop

Tags: swift

I have a for case loop in which I want to sort the created variables using their index from that loop. However, I'm not sure if there's an elegant way of doing so. here is the loop I have so far.

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String: AnyObject]

for case let playlistData as JSONDictionary in JSON {
        let playlist = Playlist(context: coreData.viewContext)
        playlist.initialize(dictionary: playlistData, key: youtube.GMSKey)
```

Here's what I want to avoid:

```
       typealias JSONDictionary = [String: AnyObject]

       var i = 0
        for case let playlistData as JSONDictionary in JSON {
            let playlist = Playlist(context: coreData.viewContext)
            playlist.initialize(dictionary: playlistData, key: youtube.GMSKey)
            // etc
            i += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641222-enumerated) in conjunction with `for case let`, you just need to move the conditional typecasting pattern into the binding of the second element in the tuple.

```
// note that variable names should be lowerCamelCase – I renamed 'JSON' to 'json'.
for case let (index, playlistData as JSONDictionary) in json.enumerated() {
    // ...
}
```

`enumerated()` returns a sequence of pairs of consecutive `Int`s starting from 0 (available inside the loop as `index`) along with the elements of the sequence you call it on.

Answer (score 2):

```
for case (index, element as JSONDictionary) in JSON.enumerated() {
  print("Item \(index): \(element)")
}
```

or

```
for (index, element) in JSON.enumerated() {
  if element as JSONDictionary {
   //
  }
}
```